# Cannot build Qt SDK from source on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, build

I've been trying to build the SDK statically on Mac OS X but I run into errors that don't make sense to me. Here is my configure command:

```
sh configure -static -opensource -universal
```

Then I build the framework using:

```
sudo make sub-src
```

The build process works well initially but after some time, I start getting errors like the ones below, there are hundred of these:

```
ranlib: for architecture: i386 file: /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/lib/libQtScript.a(ARMAssembler.o) has no symbols
ranlib: for architecture: i386 file: /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/lib/libQtScript.a(MacroAssemblerARM.o) has no symbols
```

Then after some time, the build process hits this command:

```
g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -Xarch_i386 -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -Xarch_ppc -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc -all_load -o ../../../../bin/Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Assistant .obj/debug-static/fontpanel.o .obj/debug-static/aboutdialog.o .obj/debug-static/bookmarkdialog.o .obj/debug-static/bookmarkfiltermodel.o .obj/debug-static/bookmarkitem.o .obj/debug-static/bookmarkmanager.o .obj/debug-static/bookmarkmanagerwidget.o .obj/debug-static/bookmarkmodel.o .obj/debug-static/centralwidget.o .obj/debug-static/cmdlineparser.o .obj/debug-static/contentwindow.o .obj/debug-static/findwidget.o .obj/debug-static/filternamedialog.o .obj/debug-static/helpenginewrapper.o .obj/debug-static/helpviewer.o .obj/debug-static/indexwindow.o .obj/debug-static/installdialog.o .obj/debug-static/main.o .obj/debug-static/mainwindow.o .obj/debug-static/preferencesdialog.o .obj/debug-static/qtdocinstaller.o .obj/debug-static/remotecontrol.o .obj/debug-static/searchwidget.o .obj/debug-static/topicchooser.o .obj/debug-static/xbelsupport.o .obj/debug-static/collectionconfiguration.o .obj/debug-static/helpviewer_qtb.o .obj/debug-static/moc_fontpanel.o .obj/debug-static/moc_aboutdialog.o .obj/debug-static/moc_bookmarkdialog.o .obj/debug-static/moc_bookmarkfiltermodel.o .obj/debug-static/moc_bookmarkmanager.o .obj/debug-static/moc_bookmarkmanagerwidget.o .obj/debug-static/moc_bookmarkmodel.o .obj/debug-static/moc_centralwidget.o .obj/debug-static/moc_contentwindow.o .obj/debug-static/moc_findwidget.o .obj/debug-static/moc_filternamedialog.o .obj/debug-static/moc_helpenginewrapper.o .obj/debug-static/moc_indexwindow.o .obj/debug-static/moc_installdialog.o .obj/debug-static/moc_mainwindow.o .obj/debug-static/moc_preferencesdialog.o .obj/debug-static/moc_qtdocinstaller.o .obj/debug-static/moc_remotecontrol.o .obj/debug-static/moc_searchwidget.o .obj/debug-static/moc_topicchooser.o .obj/debug-static/moc_helpviewer_qtb.o .obj/debug-static/qrc_assistant.o .obj/debug-static/qrc_assistant_images.o    -L/Users/laurent/.Trash/qt-src-4.7.1/lib -L/Users/laurent/.Trash/qt-src-4.7.1/plugins/sqldrivers -lQtHelp_debug -L/Users/laurent/.Trash/qt-src-4.7.1/lib -lQtCLucene_debug -L/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/plugins/sqldrivers -lqsqlite_debug -lQtSql_debug -lQtXml_debug -lQtGui_debug -framework Carbon -framework AppKit -lQtNetwork_debug -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreFoundation -lQtCore_debug -lz -lm -framework ApplicationServices
```

which is followed by hundreds of these lines:

```
ld: warning: qt_noop()    has different visibility (hidden) in /Users/laurent/.Trash/qt-src-4.7.1/lib/libQtHelp_debug.a(qhelpenginecore.o) and (default) in .obj/debug-static/fontpanel.o
ld: warning: QBool::operator void const*() consthas different visibility (hidden) in /Users/laurent/.Trash/qt-src-4.7.1/lib/libQtHelp_debug.a(qhelpenginecore.o) and (default) in .obj/debug-static/fontpanel.o
```

after that, I get many of these:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture ppc:
  "QCLuceneStandardAnalyzer::QCLuceneStandardAnalyzer()", referenced from:
      fulltextsearch::clucene::QHelpSearchIndexWriter::optimizeIndex()      in libQtHelp_debug.a(qhelpsearchindexwriter_clucene.o)
      fulltextsearch::clucene::QHelpSearchIndexWriter::run()     in libQtHelp_debug.a(qhelpsearchindexwriter_clucene.o)
      fulltextsearch::clucene::QHelpSearchIndexReaderClucene::boostSearchHits(QHelpEngineCore const&, QList >&, QList const&)in libQtHelp_debug.a(qhelpsearchindexreader_clucene.o)
      fulltextsearch::clucene::QHelpSearchIndexReaderClucene::run()     in libQtHelp_debug.a(qhelpsearchindexreader_clucene.o)
```

At that point, the build process stops with this error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture ppc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cc5nBJvn.out (No such file or directory)
make[4]: *** [../../../../bin/Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Assistant] Error 1
make[3]: *** [sub-assistant-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-tools-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-assistant-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
make: *** [sub-tools-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
```

My config is Snow Leopard and I'm building from the source downloaded there:
http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.1.tar.gz

Can anybody see what could be the problem? I've been working on this for hours and can't figure it out, so I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Hi. The same happen me. I've tried all posibilities for hours and hours and I don't know what happen with qt4 in static mode for Snow Leopard. The applications are  build well but these are crashed after run them. I'm desesperated. Could you write here if you find any solution out? Thank you. (Sorry for me english).

Comment: Unfortunately, I never figured it out, I just gave up as it was driving me crazy. In the end, I'm using the macdeployqt tool to build static executables on Mac OS X. You just need to specify the name of your executable and it adds all the libraries to it. It works just fine for me. More info there: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/deployment-mac.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture ppc

If you build for 10.6, AFAIK PPC is not supported.  If you want to build for PPC, then you'll probably need to build for a different target version of OS X - 10.4 or 10.5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I build for a different version of OS X? Is there a configure parameter that I need to add?

Comment: Ok I got the reply there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778794/cannot-build-qt-sdk-from-source-on-mac-os-x Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.